# JCombobox должен показать список ID и отобразить полученные результат

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

На данный момент у меня программа, в которой содержаться данные про дома, которые выставлены на продажу. Я могу изменять данные, нажав на кнопку `edit`, затем сохранять их. Так же вызвав `dialog`, есть возможность добавить новый дом с данными в главный интрефейс и соответсвенно удалить дом из списка.

Дома, которые уже сохранены в программе, изначально имеют данные, которые содержаться в  `two dimension array` таким образом:

```
String[][] records = {{"1", "113 The Maltings", "Dublin 8", "2", "1", "155500.00", "House1.jpg", "(087) 9011135"},
               {"2", "78 Newington Lodge", "Dublin 14", "3", "2", "310000.00", "House2.jpg", "(087) 9010580"},
               {"3", "62 Bohernabreena Road", "Dublin 24", "3", "1", "220000.00", "House3.jpg", "(087) 6023159"},
               {"4", "18 Castledevitt Park", "Dublin 15", "3", "3", "325000.00", "House4.jpg", "(087) 9010580"},
               {"5", "40 Dunsawny Road", "Swords", "3", "19", "245000.00", "House5.jpg", "(087) 9011135"}
    };
```

У меня есть array:

```
ArrayList<House> houseList = new ArrayList<House>();
```

И вот такой вот конструктор в драйвер классе:

```
public HouseApplication() {
        super("Estate Agent Application");
        for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
            houseList.add(new House(Integer.parseInt(records[i][0]), records[i][1], records[i][2], Integer.parseInt(records[i][3]), 
                    Integer.parseInt(records[i][4]), Double.parseDouble(records[i][5]), records[i][6], records[i][7]));
        }
        currentItem = 0;
        initComponents();   
    }
```

Не могу справиться со следующем заданием. Необходимо, чтобы ID генерированная самостоятельно и не был `hardcoded`. Никак не могу поставить его в конструктор просто как `variable`, например: `int id,` ...
И далее необходимо открыть диалог, в котором будет `JCombobox` из генерируемых ID, тех домов, которые уже есть в системе.  Пока что есть наработки, но когда я выбираю ID, и нажимаю на ok, то то, что я выбрала, не отображается.

```
String [] id = new String[records.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < records.length; i++)
        {
           id[i] = records[i][0];
        }

     String i = (String) JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
     HouseApplication.this, "Choose house id: ", "ID", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, id, records);
     int ID = Integer.parseInt(i);
```

И в итоге, когда я из `JComboBox` выбирают подходящее мне `ID` и нажимаю на OK, программа должна открыть именно тот `record`, на котором есть соответсвующие `ID`.

**UPDATE 1**

Вот такой выбор мне предоставляется.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И даже если я вбираю какое-либо значение, и нажимаю на ok, то все равно не открывается то, что я выбрала.
Получается, что чтобы высвечивалось обычное ID, мне можно попробовать создать еще один класс. Когда создаю этот класс и пишу тот код, который вы мне предоставили, то `Objects.requireNonNull( house );` выдает следующую ошибку `Objects cannot be resolved`.
Что необходимо сделать, чтобы решить это проблему?

Comment: `Objects` - это `java.util.Objects`, содержит набор полезных статических методов. Доступен с _Java 7_. Если у вас JDK 7 или 8, достаточно написать `import`, если 6, то стоит уточнять этот момент в вопросах, Oracle, по-моему, уже и 7ую с поддержки снял.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод:

```
JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
    Component parentComponent,
    Object message, String title, int messageType, Icon icon,
    Object[] selectionValues, Object initialSelectionValue): Object
```

последними двумя параметрами принимает массив значений, из которых пользователь будет выбирать, и выбранное по-умолчанию значение (в случае выпадающего списка - тот элемент, который будет показан при открытии окна).

В вашем случае, есть список `houseList`, предположу, что типа `List<House>`, и нужно выбрать один из его элементов.

```
House chosenOne = (House)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
                HouseApplication.this,
                "Choose now...", "The Choice of a Lifetime",
                JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
                houseList.toArray(), // преобразуем список в массив
                null                 // элемент по-умолчанию не важен
    );
if ( chosenOne == null ) return;  //пользователь нажал "Cancel"

int id = chosenOne.getId(); // или как там у вашего объекта взять ид
```

**Важно:** текст в элементе выпадающего списка берется методом `toString` (т.е. `House.toString()`), элемент по-умолчанию сравнивается с элементами списка вызовом `equals`.

Если метод `house.toString()` возвращает неподходящую строку, можно завернуть объекты `House` в свой объект:

```
class HouseWrapper {
    House house;
    public HouseWrapper( House house ) {
        Objects.requireNonNull( house );
        this.house = house;
    }

    public House house() {
        return house;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // возвращает строку, использующую поля House в нужном формате
        return house.getName() + " [" + house.getPhone() + "]";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals( Object other ) {
        if ( other == null ) return false;
        if ( other == this ) return true;
        if ( !HouseWrapper.class.equals( other.getClass() ) ) return false;
        return Objects.equals( house, ((HouseWrapper)other).house );
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return house.hashCode();
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
searchItem.addActionListener( event -> {
    // преобразуем список House в массив HouseWrapper
    HouseWrapper[] choices = houseList.stream()
        .map( HouseWrapper::new )
        .toArray( HouseWrapper[]::new );

    HouseWrapper chosenOne = (HouseWrapper)JOptionPane.showInputDialog(
            null,
            "Choose now...", "The Choice of a Lifetime",
            JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE, null,
            choices, null );

    if ( chosenOne == null ) return;
    House chosenHouse = chosenOne.house();
    // что-то сделать с выбором пользователя
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за столь развернутый ответ. Вы приблизили мое понимание этого задания. Не могли бы вы посмотреть на мой вопрос, я его обновила. К сожалению, еще не до конца разобралась в проблеме.

Comment: По тексту в комбобоксе - это вывод непереопределенного `object.toString()` (я упомянул, но возможно недостаточно заострил внимание). Если вы можете править код класса `House`, просто добавьте `public String toString()` и верните какую-нибудь осмысленную строку.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное за столь подробное объяснение! Все работает!